# multiple images multiple sounds issue android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am fairly new to android eclipse and I am having a slight issue with an app I'm making. Basically I want to have 6 images, once you click on an image a set sound will play. The problem I'm having is no matter which image is clicked the same sound occurs. Below is my code for the activity, any help will be much appreciated. I have tried getting sound pools to work but I haven't find a good example to follow and not been able to get it to work.

```
package org.example.tuner;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.R.raw;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;

    public class GuitarTunerActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp;


        ImageView estring, astring;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        estring = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.estring);
        estring.setOnTouchListener(this);

        astring = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.astring);
        astring.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int resId;
            estring = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.estring);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                resId = R.raw.e;
                System.out.println("Image is Touched");
                break;

                default:
                    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.release();
            }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
            mp.start();
            return true;            
        }
        public boolean onTouch1(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int resId;
            astring = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.astring);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                resId = R.raw.a;
                System.out.println("Image is Touched");
                break;

                default:
                    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.release();
            }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
            mp.start();
            return true;


        }
}
```

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a switch case in your `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`

```
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.estrsing: resId = R.raw.e; break;

        case R.id.astrsing: resId = R.raw.a; break;

   } 
   ...
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
   mp.start();
```

All touch events will be handled by the same method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand what does `setOnTouchListener(this);` mean. When you set listener via `setOnTouchListener()`, you must provide it with object implementing `OnTouchListener` interface, in your case - `GuitarTunerActivity`. `OnTouchListener` interface has `onTouch()` callback, which is called when you touch the View and which you've implemented, but `onTouch1()` is not part of that interface and so will never be called. So, you need to add `switch` in your `onTouch()` method, to check which View was touched.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.estrsing: 
           resId = R.raw.e;
           break;
      case R.id.astrsing:
           resId = R.raw.a; 
           break;
}
```

**edit** btw, you don't really need `OnTouchListener`, `View.OnClickListener` will suit your case better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    estring = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.estring);
    estring.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // do stub
            return false;
        }
    });
    astring = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.astring);
    astring.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // do stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```